# LNK2001 Error on basic_istream, basic_ostream

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I'm trying to get around these link errors:

```
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public void __thiscall std::basic_ostream(char,struc std::char_traits<char>>::_0sfx(void)"
```

I used Visual Studio C++ 2010, and tried with Visual Studio C++ 6.0, but still the same errors show up.

The object file is found, so I am suspecting that it cannot find the implementation of the std library? I've tried /nodefaultlib option on a few libraries (libc.lib, libcmt.lib, msvcrt.lib, etc) but did not improve the situation at all.

Could someone explain why the error occurs and where I should look ?

Tried the solutions suggested in other similar questions but they either are not applicable or do not resolve the problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should remove /nodefaultlib option.

Answer (score 0):

This problem could arise if some of your libraries are linked static while other dynamically.

Basically if you have both codes compiled with the static version of `CRT` (that's compiler switch `/MT` and `/MTd`) and dynamic version of `CRT` (switch `/MD`, `/MDd`). 
You can see what your project is using in `Project Properies - c++ - Code Generaion - Runtime Library`)

Make sure all your libraries are compiled with the same switch as you project.

Comment: thanks @tozka, but the thing is right now I don't have access to the source code of the libraries. I used the /MD switch for compiling the add on code. Will try to recompile with /MDd (didn't realize it might be the cause), and let u know if it works. Additionally, it's not a Visual Studio project, I obtained a bunch of third party libraries I need to use only in the form of header files and .lib and .dlls

Comment: At least you can make sure that all your libraries are either static or all are DLLs.

Comment: I have both static and dlls. Tried the compile switches. Did not solve the problem.